# peerguardian / moblock installation on raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, security

Since I'm thinking of using my pi to do some downloads, i would like to setup a peerblock/peerguardian equivalent.

I searched the internet, and I've [found this](http://lazydroid.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-peerguardian-moblock-setup/).

i'm using latest raspbmc,

```
cat /scripts/upd_hist/build_info
raspbmc-rls-1.0-hardfp-b20130616-u20130616
```

uname output:

```
Linux raspbmc 3.6.11 #2 PREEMPT Sat Jun 15 21:45:28 UTC 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

./autogen.sh output:

```
pglgui/Makefile.am:65: `%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension
pglgui/Makefile.am:81: `%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension
```

./configure –without-qt4 –disable-dbus output:

```
pgl.......................................... : Version 2.2.2
Prefix....................................... : /usr/local
Exec_Prefix.................................. : ${prefix}
Initd........................................ : ${prefix}/etc/init.d
Logdir....................................... : ${prefix}/var/log/pgl
Piddir....................................... : ${prefix}/var/run
Tmpdir....................................... : /tmp
Blocklists................................... : ${prefix}/var/spool/pgl
Localblocklist............................... : ${prefix}/etc/pgl/blocklists.local
Masterblocklist.............................. : ${prefix}/var/lib/pgl
LSB (use built-in functions if empty)........ :

logrotate.................................... : yes
cron......................................... : yes
networkmanager............................... : yes
zlib......................................... : yes
dbus......................................... : no
lowmem....................................... : no
QT-gui....................................... : no

.............................................
Developer debug:
PGLD_CFLAGS:
PGLD_CPPFLAGS:   -DVERSION=\"2.2.2\" -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"pgl\" -DPIDFILE=\"${prefix}/var/run/pgld.pid\"   -DHAVE_ZLIB
PGLD_LDFLAGS:
PGLD_LIBS: -lnetfilter_queue -lnfnetlink   -lz
QT_CXXFLAGS:
QT_CPPFLAGS: -DVERSION=\"2.2.2\" -DPGLCMDDEFAULTSPATH=\"${exec_prefix}/lib/pgl/pglcmd.defaults\" -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
QT_LDFLAGS:
QT_LIBS:'
```

make output (where the error occurs):

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mushi/peerguardian/pgl-2.2.2/pgld'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DVERSION=\"2.2.2\" -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"pgl\" -DPIDFILE=\"/usr/local/var/run/pgld.pid\"   -DHAVE_ZLIB   -g -O2 -MT pgld.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/pgld.Tpo -c -o pgld.o `test -f 'src/pgld.c' || echo './'`src/pgld.c
In file included from /usr/include/linux/kernel.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/linux/sysctl.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/linux/netfilter.h:6,
                 from /usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4.h:8,
                 from src/pgld.h:42,
                 from src/pgld.c:22:
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:8:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_long_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:9:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:10:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:11:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:12:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:13:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:14:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:15:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:18:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:19:2: error: unknown type name '__kernel_ulong_t'
/usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h:21:22: error: '__kernel_ulong_t' undeclared here (not in a function)
make[2]: *** [pgld.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mushi/peerguardian/pgl-2.2.2/pgld'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mushi/peerguardian/pgl-2.2.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2'
```

trying to compile pgl 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the "found this" page =)

Please, for God's sake don't run anything as superuser, except `sudo make install` step.

Looks, like raspbmc is missing some kernel header files, there are two ways to correct this problem:

1. you may use `apt-get` to install linux-headers, but this is likely to break your raspbmc installation, since the raspbmc explicitly warns against using `apt-get`.
2. you may use another `raspbian` installation to compile the peerguardian and then tar-copy-untar and `sudo make install` on your raspbmc.

Personally, I'd prefer the latter.

Comment: i don't understand `headless` and `raspbmc` in the same sentence, do you have TV/monitor attached or not? if not, what's the purpose of raspbmc?

Comment: i've completed the original question with all the outputs i get.
my plan is to use pi as a mediacenter and for torrent download,using cron to schedule these activities. i don't have X installed.
thank you for your time!

Comment: updated the answer. the best way seems to use another SD card to temporary install raspbian to compile peerguardian.

Comment: Thank you. for the moment I don't have a second card, but will try. maybe someone else interested could do it meanwhile?.. =)

Comment: i've made the compiled build available at lazydroid.com/files/pgl-2.2.2-compiled.tgz -- download, untar and `sudo make install`. this file will be available for a few days.

Comment: Thanks! I got it - i will try that in the weekend and give feedback later!

Comment: weekend came early :) 
I've installed sucessfully! thank you for all your help. now i must configure it! 
i'm sure that this is helpful for other pi users that use it to download. thanks again, kudus!

Comment: okay, it's set up. its so easy to configure, a simple google search told me which files i -could- edit (because it is pre-configured from start and starts running straight away) and that's it! now i just have to configure rtorrent :) 
Thanks! apparently i have to have more reputation to rate your answer even better.

oh, and please consider making that link with the pre-compiled peerguardian permanent ;)

Comment: I could keep the file available, but I don't think I'd recompile it every time new version of peerguardian comes out, so it might get old/stale soon enough.

Comment: maybe you can ask others to do it when you release a new version. ask them to put a link on the comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to edit /usr/include/linux/sysinfo.h and add the following code :

```
#ifndef __kernel_long_t
typedef long     __kernel_long_t;
typedef unsigned long   __kernel_ulong_t;
#endif
```

it is ugly but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try running all the build steps as sudo.  I've often found that without that things often don't compile correctly.  Other than that, my next guess would be that you're missing somekind of dependency.

Comment: didn't work, same error...

Comment: According to the author, the gui dependencies "may or may not be required".  Have you tried compiling with them?

Comment: yes.. i'm stuck. so little information online about how to correctly set this up on a pi...